# How to print comments in lex?

Tags: comments, lex, lexical-analysis

So the title might be a little bit misleading, but I can't think of any better way to phrase it.

Basically, I'm writing a lexical-scanner using cygwin/lex. A part of the code reads a token /* . It the goes into a predefined state C_COMMENT, and ends when C_COMMENT"/*". Below is the actual code

```
"/*" {BEGIN(C_COMMENT); printf("%d: /*", linenum++);}
<C_COMMENT>"*/" { BEGIN(INITIAL); printf("*/\n"); }
<C_COMMENT>.    {printf("%s",yytext);}
```

The code works when the comment is in a single line, such as

```
/* * Example of comment */
```

It will print the current line number, with the comment behind. But it doesn't work if the comment spans multiple lines. Rewriting the 3rd line into

```
<C_COMMENT>.    {printf("%s",yytext);
                 printf("\n");}
```

doesn't work. It will result in \n printed for every letter in the comment. I'm guessing it has something to do with **C** having no strings or maybe I'm using the states wrong.

Hope someone will be able to help me out :)

Also if there's any other info you need, just ask, and I'll provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The easiest way to echo the token scanned by a pattern is to use the special action `ECHO`:

   ```
   "/*"            { printf("%d: ", linenum++); ECHO; BEGIN(C_COMMENT); }
   <C_COMMENT>"*/" { ECHO; BEGIN(INITIAL); }
   <C_COMMENT>.    { ECHO; }
   ```
2. None of the above rules matches a newline inside a comment, because in (f)lex `.` doesn't match newlines:

   ```
   <C_COMMENT>\n   { linenum++; ECHO; }
   ```
3. A faster way of recognizing C comments is with a single regular expression, although it's a little hard to read:

   ```
   [/][*][^*]*[*]+([^/*][^*][*]+)*[/]
   ```

   In this case, you'll have to rescan the comment to count newlines, unless you get flex to do the line number counting.
4. flex scanners maintain a line number count in `yylineno`, if you request that feature (using `%option yylineno`). It's often more efficient and always more reliable than keeping the count yourself. However, in the action, the value of `yylineno` is the line number count at the end of the pattern, not at the beginning, which can be misleading for multiline patterns. A common workaround is to save the value of `yylineno` in another variable at the beginning of the token scan.